# What is the optimal filter?

Tags: filter, signals, filtering, signal-processing

I am trying to find the optimal filter for a given problem. The problem is the following: Let's suppose that we have a signal defined as: `r(t) = z(t) + xi(t)`, where `z(t)` is a smooth function and `xi(t)` is white Gaussian noise.

The question is to find the optimal filter for eliminating the Gaussian noise `xi(t)` if nothing is known about the smooth signal `z(t)`?.

While searching I came across the Kalman Filter, which is known for being an optimal filter. However, I do not think that KL is the best the right one as we do not know anything about `z`.

Comment: If you know nothing about the signal you're trying to detect, there's not a lot you can do here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about signal-processing theory, not programming (try https://dsp.stackexchange.com).